# Calling an empty base class function, what happens at compile time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-optimization

How does the compiler treat a complete empty function to behave at runtime?

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void execute(){ /* always empty */ }
};
```

example usage:

```
int main()
{

    Base b;
    b.execute();

    return 0;

}
```

---

Am creating an entity system which should be able to have sub-classes which are only holding data. Those are called `Properties`. Some need to have a manipulation function to conclude the data. These classes are called `Component`.

The purpose is to be able to add functionality to a class at run-time and even later with additional shared libraries.

Due to the flexibility needed, and the wish to keep it as simple as possible, I came up with a shared `Base` class for the `Properties` and `Component` classes. See the code-block below.

However, the  class `Base` contains the function `execute()` and is invoked in the final class `Container` for all the properties and components assigned to that class.

Maybe it is better to split the `Property` and `Component` entirely into two different identities, however they will rely on each other heavily, e.g. A property could be a transform (position, scale, quaternion, matrix) while a component can be an animation of that quaternion in the transform.

```
#include <vector>

class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void execute(){ /* always empty */ }
};

class Property // as manny will be
: public Base
{
    public:
    /* specifics */
};

class Component // as manny will be
: public Base
{
    public:
    /* specifics */
    virtual void execute(){ /* do whatever */ }
};

class Container
{
    public:
    std::vector<Base*> list;
    virtual void execute()
    {
        std::vector<Base>::iterator iterator = list.begin(), end = list.end();
        while( iterator != end )
            ( *iterator )->execute();
    }

}
```

Not knowing what the compiler actually does besides generating binaries, I don't think it would be an equivalent of a debug session going line by line.

How does the compiler treat such an empty function, would it be better to move the `function execute();` to class `Component` as first declaration. Then add `enum{ Property, Component };` to class `Property` so a if-statement can determine to call the execution function.

Comment: I downvoted this because it is another "I stare at some code and make assumptions over compiler-work"-question. The only answer to all of these question: Write the most logical and readable code possible, then optimize what you find to be too slow by measurement.

Comment: If I understand the question you didn't ask, its: Would adding more layers in the hierarchy deriving from Base have an additional runtime cost? The answer is no if only the most derived class actually does anything in execute(). If it calls a parent class' execute and the function is in another translation unit then it would incur an additional function call.

Comment: @qeadz: not quit, although your answer did remove another insecurity which I would target after getting input out of this question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: If you interprete a question as an assumption, you should read a dictionairy.

Comment: Are you running in debug or release mode?  In release mode, the compiler may optimize out the call to an empty function and not even bother with the virtual function table mechanism.

Comment: Debug for now, but goal is release ofcourse. Assuming, eh, you're right you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual functions are very cheap to call, but depending on the number of different sub-classes a switch could be faster (the reason is that a switch will not create another execution context) but of course a lot less flexible. This is especially true if to implement the body of `execute` method most of them will share part of the processing and data access (like for example for different instructions of a virtual machine) because part of that could be cached out of the loop.

Keeping properties in the same container and leaving them with an empty `execute` method doesn't seem reasonable to me, but this could be just lack of context of the problem being solved.

The general rule is however to stop assuming and start measuring, with real data and real usage pattern. Performance forecasting is today very complex (almost impossibly complex) because CPUs are little monsters of complexity on their own and there are many of them. You need to test to find where the time is spent... guessing doesn't work that well.

My first approach would be using virtual functions and keeping things as simple as possible. Inlining those functions in a loop would only come later if I measure that the dispatch overhead is the problem and that there are no bigger wins to be searched in other areas.

Comment: The context of this system is being able to add functionallity to a class at runtime. The number of different sub-classes is undefined. It should be able to even add more at a later stage by linking to a new shared library. --- Think it is time to learn the inline keyword now too.

Comment: @Ruijter: to create an "open" system a virtual function is then the best option... however this approach would still require recompiling the program (or at least dynamically loading a library: something that is not covered by the C++ standard but for which most platforms provide specific solutions). Another option to provide true run-time extensibility (i.e. adding new features to a program without even stopping it) is to implement/embed a full extension language; more complex but doable.